# Show current keyboard layout

Tags: linux, slackware

One can use

> loadkeys

command to set appropriate `keyboard layout`. My question is how can I check the currently selected layout (in the console mode)?

Answer (score 6):

You can check keyboard file for keyboard layout information...

```
nano /etc/default/keyboard
```

OUTPUT:

```
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE
# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.
XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="us"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS=""
BACKSPACE="guess"
```

Value of XKBLAYOUT is the layout of keyboard. Change it to another possible value and reboot the machine to take effects.

Comment: Sorry but have no `keyboard` file on my system...

Comment: Which OS are you exactly using?

Comment: It's Slackware 14.2

Comment: Slackware doesn't use /etc/default/keyboard, it uses /etc/rc.d/rc.keymap instead.

Comment: The question doesn't ask for a partircular distro and this response is very distro specific. Indeed the cited file didn't ever exist in any of the RedHate related distros (Fedora, RHEL, Centos, Suse, Rocky Linux, etc)

Answer (score 5):

Command:

`localectl status`

Output:

```
  System Locale: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
  VC Keymap: us
  X11 Layout: us
```

Comment: This doesn't show the *current* locale if you have several enabled, e.g. `se,us`. It just shows `se,us`.

Comment: This worked for me in both Debian/Ubuntu and RedHat based distros, and the comand is part of the general systemd package, so it seems to be available in any modern Linux distribution. So this seems the most appropriate answer to me.

Answer (score 3):

This is a workaround but...it works

```
xset -q | grep LED | awk '{ print $10 }')
```

the output is a number made of 8 digits corresponding to.. something related to the layout (in my case 00000000 for gb and 00001000 for it). Care to the fact that this number changes if you have CAPS LOCK enabled (the same number but +1).
If you want it as a string you can edit my simple script.

```
#!/bin/sh
COMMAND=$(xset -q | grep LED | awk '{ print $10 }')

case "$COMMAND" in

 "00000000"|"00000001") LAYOUT="uk" ;;

 "00001000"|"00001001") LAYOUT="it" ;;

  *) LAYOUT="??" ;;

esac

echo $LAYOUT
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for the command *dumpkeys*

Comment: Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console

Comment: @TheTechRobotheNerd You need sudo or root permissions. This a poor answer though. It just dumps a list of every key on the keyboard with what each one does.

Answer (score 1):

As referenced by the man page for setfont, you could use [showconsolefont](https://linux.die.net/man/8/showconsolefont). As referenced by the manpage for loadkeys, you could use [dumpkeys](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dumpkeys.1.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is way with one direction.

loadkeys modify kernel keyboard driver's translation table by loadind keyboard keymap file.

If nobody issue loadkeys you can check /etc/rc.d/rc.keymap file for loaded keymap.

You can check content of kernel keyboard driver's translation table using dumpkeys. There are no tool to find from which keymap file data was loaded into table.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this script to find out which keyboard layout you are using:

```
#!/bin/bash
var=" $(xset -q | grep -i "led mask" | grep -o "....1...")"
if [ -z $var ]
then
    echo "Using the first layout"
else
    echo "Using the second one"
fi
```